Canning didn’t water bath
I didn’t water bath my chow chow last night. What should I do? Can I water bath them the next day? Do I have to throw them away? They all sealed.

Is this a duplicate of Cans are all sealed, but I forgot to boil the closed jars - should I boil them now? I'm not asking this rhetorically; I'm honestly not sure.
